# On linux is there a commonly used / conventional sub-directory that is used for user specific program settings

Tags: linux, filesystems, user-profiles

On linux, many programs store user specific profile settings in a hidden dot file in the users home directory.  Other programs create their own uniquely named hidden dot directory and put one or more files inside their to do the same job.

Is there any existing or emerging convention / common hidden dot directory (such as .settings or .profile) where developers of new programs can put their user specific profile settings to minimise the home directory clutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [convention](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html), '.config' should contain settings for a local user.
Follow [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33945/215519) answer.